# Bootstrap alerts not closing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble closing my bootstrap alert. I have my jquery declared before bootstrap and the alerts still do not close. The code for the alert is below. Any ideas?

```
  <!-- jquery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
     <strong>Yay</strong> Your email has been added!
  </div>
```

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969850/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-does-not-work/30971313#30971313.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to add Twitter Bootstrap core JS.

```html
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  <strong>Yay</strong> Your email has been added!
</div>
```